# Re-writing the Hosts file does not update the next IP connection

Tags: c#, .net, dns, hosts

We have a written a C# application that communicates with any one of a group of IP in the cloud.
Any one of which may not be working.  We use the URL of the address as the IIS server is expecting a Host Header Name in order to route to the correct application interface.

So we set the Hosts file to point the URL at an IP.
We then send a command at the URL to get back the server time.
This tells us the connection is working.

If we don't get a response we assume the connection is dead.  We then write a new IP from a list into the Hosts file and we try again.

This is where we hit a bug.  The application doesn't seem to see the Hosts file has changed and uses the old (bad) IP.

There is no caching built into the application so we are assuming that Windows is caching for us.

We've tried to flush caches with:

ipconfig /flushdns
arp -d *
nbtstat -R

We still get the same problem.
Any thoughts on how to clear the cache?

Comment: Why not just try a new ip from the C# code rather than change hosts file - especially as it will require admin writes to change the file?

Comment: Is it not better to handle this at the server farm with one address pointed at a load balancer or some such?  Failing that a wrapper class for whatever connection object you use that maintains the state of each ip address and automatically routes to working ip addresses.

Comment: I would have to agree with Robb at the very least you should have a single server that will always respond to a request.  You can use that server to request and send a configuration file.  You would be better of keep track if a server is online/offline I would think on a per client basis.  The amount of processing power to respond to such a response from a client would be minimial.

Comment: I'd love to have a central load balanced server.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't address this at the server end (e.g. a load balancer, etc), then just use the IP address list in your code:

```
var req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://" + IPAdd.ToString() + "/path_to_query_time");
((HttpWebRequest)req).Host = "yourhostheaderhere";
var resp = req.GetResponse();
//If things have gone wrong here, change IPAdd to the next IP address and start over.
```

Don't go messing with the users settings to try and solve a problem in your application that's of your own making.

Comment: Thanks for the thought.  There are no users.  This is so our automated control systems around the world can communicate back to the main servers.

Comment: @Richard - even with no users, I think it'll be easier to manage this at the app level rather than trying to force things through the hosts file.

Comment: The connection is made with the web service proxy file generated from a wsdl.  I'll look if your code can be adapted to fit into this. Thanks